# How may I detect requests generated by other requests using Ruby and Puma?

Tags: ruby, http, request, emerald-framework

Let me try to explain what I need.

When I include a library like **Bootstrap** in my HTML page and this page is loaded, the library main files are also loaded. Most of the times the library files require other files. Since I used Bootstrap as an example, let's consider `glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg`, `glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf`, `glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` and `glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2`, all of them part of Bootstrap.

I am writing a **Rack** middleware to deal with the requests from my application. One of the tasks of this middleware is to modify the requests according to certain conventions. For instance, in my application Bootstrap would be located at this path

```
ENV['HOME']/my_app/web/libraries/bootstrap/
```

and its main CSS file would then be

```
ENV['HOME']/my_app/web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

And, when loaded, it would generate new requests for all these files I mentioned above.

What I need is identify that a certain file, say `glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg`, was required by another one, so I may use my Rack middleware to change its location accordingly. Like:

```
Requested file:
    `glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg`
Requested-by:
    http://my_app_domain.com/web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
Request address:
    http://my_domain_app.com/web/libraries/bootstrap/css/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
```

I though about starting a thread to each new request. Then I would have only to consider the address of the main file as the base-address and prepend it to every sub-request generated by that file.

I would love to hear your ideas about this. Any suggestion of a better way to do the same?

**EDIT: (spickermann's question)**

No, this is not the point. Maybe I wasn't clear, then I'll try to put it in other words.

Consider the following structure:

```
ENV['HOME']/my_app/web/libraries/library1/
                                |        |
                                |        |_ a_css_file.css
                                |        |_ a_jpeg_file.jpg
                                |
                                /library2/
                                         |
                                         |_ another_css_file.css
                                         |_ a_jpeg_file.jpg
```

Let's assume my middleware receives a request for a file named `a_jpeg_file.jpg`. We have two files with the same name, one in `library1` and other in `library2`.

The only way for me to decide which file to serve is if I may know if `a_jpeg_file.jpg` was required by `a_css_file.css` or by `another_css_file.css`.

In the first case I'd prepend the path to `library1` to the file and serve `ENV['HOME']/my_app/web/libraries/library1/`. In the other case I  prepend the path to `library2` and serve `ENV['HOME']/my_app/web/libraries/library2/`.

In both cases I need to know which file generated the request for `a_jpeg_file.jpg`.

In other words, I need to know which library-context required a certain file.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just add "my_app/web/libraries/bootstrap/css" to your `view_folders` array. Then, when a file is requested, you walk through each view folder, see if there's this file there. If there is, stop searching and serve it.

Comment: But first, check REFERER http header. It might contain what you need (but I thiink it will contain the page url)

Comment: Okay, @SergioTulentsev. But it happens that Bootstrap was only an example. My middleware must be capable of doing this to ANY library I use in my app.

Comment: Now, this REFERER sounds good. Il check it and all other HTTP headers. I think you are robably riht in this and this may b the right direction.

Comment: The useragent (browser) will not tell you which FILE requested another FILE. Referrer will tell you which URL the useragent was on that requested the resource.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand the problem. Why can't you build the correct path in the first place? Why do you want to fix the path only under certain conditions, but not always?

Comment: I'll edit to make it more clear. Thanks for pointing this fact.

Comment: @spickermann, I edited the question, trying to make it clearer.

Comment: Maybe you can parametrize your resource, like `my-image.jpg?dir='dir1'` and parse the params on your middleware. Similar approach is done by Rails to cache the assets. Also you can use some cryptho function that encrypt and decrypt the info in the params, like `image.jpt?info=HughYF65fFj7t...`  and then you decrypt the info in your midleware

Comment: Nice suggestion, @Andrés. Gonna try something like this. Would you mind to post this as an answer? The time for this bounty is almost finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can parametrize your resource, `like my-image.jpg?dir='dir1'` and parse the params on your middleware. Similar approach is done by Rails to cache the assets. Also you can use some crypt function that encrypt and decrypt the info in the params, like `image.jpt?info=HughYF65fFj7t...` and then you decrypt the info in your midleware and use the info you sent.